# How can I compute the cohomology of a complement?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Given a compact "nice" topological space $X$ and a closed subspace $Z$, is there any way to relate the cohomology of $U=X-Z$ with $X$ and $Z$? I know there is the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,Z)$, but I'm not sure if
$$
H^*(X,Z) \cong H^*(U)
$$

Comment: It's not. Look up compactly supported cohomology, which does have a long exact sequence of this form, and which has various known relationships to ordinary (co)homology.

Comment: If $Z$ is a divisor with normal crossings, then IIRC, $H^*(U) \simeq H^*(X, \Omega^*(\log Z))$, where $\Omega^*(\log Z)$ is intuitively the de Rham complex extended by differentials with log poles along $Z$, e.g. $\frac{dx}{x}$ for $x \in \mathscr{I}_Z$.  (Note: where I saw this was in an algebraic geometry context.)

Comment: When you write this isomorphism do you mean $H^n(U) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q = n} H^p(X, \Omega^q(\log Z))$?

Comment: I looked up this identity and it holds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For example, consider just homology of $D^2$  and its boundary $S^1$. $H_1(D^2,S_1)=\mathbb Z$ while $D^n-S^1$ is contractible.

On the other hand, there is a result known as Alexander Duality for manifolds:

$$\tilde{H}^k(M) \cong \tilde{H}_{n-k-1}(S^n-M),$$

where these are reduced (co)homology, but this is a very partial result, I don't know of anything stronger.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801770/homology-of-knot-complement) for complements of $1$ manifolds (compact) in $3$ manifolds as well.

Comment: You slightly misstated the AD statement.

Comment: sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer.  Suppose $V\subset Z\subset X$ with the closure of $V$ in the interior of $Z$.  Excision gives $H^n(X,Z)\cong H^n(X-V,Z-V)$.  Suppose $Z,V$ are nice enough so that $H^n(X-V)\to H^n(X-Z)$ is an isomorphism.  With the long exact sequence of the pair $(X-V,Z-V)$, if we did have an isomorphism $H^n(X,Z)\cong H^n(X-Z)$, we would need $H^*(Z-V)\cong 0$, which is roughly that the "boundary" of $Z$ is homologically trivial.

In Andres's example of $(D^2,S^1)$, the $Z=S^1$ is not homologically trivial.

Another example is $(S^2,x_0)$, where $S^2-x_0$ is nullhomotopic, but $H^*(S^2,x_0)$ is reduced cohomology of $S^2$.  (The point has  a "boundary" which is an $S^1$.)